# As per Advaita, does Nirguna Nirakara Brahman has an Universal Mind?

Tags: advaita, brahman

Few days ago I was going through a post. I don't remember the exact question or who asked it, but i think the question was something like this - why did Brahman create the universe or why did Brahman become from ONE to Many? ... Anyway, Mr. Pradip's answer to that was something like this - "Brahman was bored or afraid and so he became the universe".

My question to  all Advaitins here including Mr.Pradip, do you all think nirguna nirakara Brahman in the paramarthika/absolute state (before the manifestation of jivas and jagat) has an universal mind of ITS own, through which IT desires to become all this multiplicity? ... I am not talking about the individual mind or ego of the jiva, but an infinite universal collective mind. Does something like that exist in paramarthika? If not how does Brahman think - I am alone or I am bored?

Comment: No Nirguna Brahman doesn't have a mind of any kind. Saguna Brahma has universal mind. Mind means thinking and there different parts to it. Brahman who is Nirguna has no parts no is not capable of thinking or memory. Nirguna Brahman is pure witness. Pradip's answer is wrong. Brahman did not create the Universe, Brahman is Akartha. Brahman didn't become many from one. Brahman even now is still one. What you see as many has always existed as many.

Comment: Very astute of you @TheCrimsonUniverse to catch my sloppiness:) Now I understand why MrGreenGold was objecting to my answer to that question.

Comment: @MrGreenGold ... if Nirguna Brahman doesn't become many from one, then who does? If you say its maya who does everything and brahman does nothing, then you're making maya a separate entity ... Advaita says everything is brahman (sarvam khalvidam brahma) ... Since everything around us are simply nama and rupa (manifestations of Brahman) wouldn't it be correct to say that Brahman from ITS infinite spirit state, manifests as matter? ... Just like clay becomes various pots, same way Brahman becomes jivas and jagat. What do you think?

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse you have asked a very important question. And Pradip's new answer is correct. See this is slightly tricky to understand, it is true that it is Maya which creates the Universe and yes Maya is different from Brahman and yes Everything is Brahman.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Now this sounds confusing. Because Maya doesn't exist. When we say Maya creates Universe we mean Maya shows a Universe that doesn't exist. The one has been not split into many it is only a illusion created by Maya, which is itself an illusion. When it's said sarvam khalvidam Brahma we don't mean for eg a Rock is Brahma. It means the underlying reality of the Rock is Brahma and that underlying relaity is being distorted by Maya as a Rock, the Rock doesn't even exist. This is tricky.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse The one Brahma is now one, in the past one and in the future is also one. It has not split. The variety of splits you see is an illusion by Maya so this illusion is not caused by Brahma so Brahma didn't create it.

Comment: May i know what causes this illusion? ... I mean, what causes maya (which actually doesn't exist) to project a false/distorted appearance (of the world)?

Comment: Kalasarpa yoga has begun @MrGreenGold

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti what do you mean? Kalasarpa yoga??

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Maya is uncaused as it is there from eternity and will stay on for eternity. Avidya, Mula avidya etc are different names approximately. Please read Brahma Sutra Bhashya, starting Adhyasa Bhasya section of Adi Shankara where he explains this. The non existence of Maya is not exactly like non existence of other imaginary things. It's actually technically called sad asad vilakshana. Neither exists nor not exists unique. Maya doe'snt exist also does not not exist. It's unique.

Comment: @MrGreenGold the answers which you have written is a result of kalasarpa period on humanity

Comment: Thank you Mr.GreenGold. I have a BrahmaSutra sitting in my wishlist. Its translated by Vireswarananda. I hope it is a good translation. :)

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti what?? Does it mean is it good or bad?? When did the Kalasarpa period start, when does it end??

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse its good, but its a summary, a detailed translation is by Swami Gambhirananda can be referenced if you don't understand certain things.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti so the answers written by all the people here on stack exchange is a result on kalasarpa yoga?? Including your comments and answers?? Are your comments also a result of kalasarpa yoga on humanity?

Comment: @Mr.GreenGold ... i just checked a few sample pages of Gambhirananda's Brahma Sutra that you recommended. The language used there is not completely lucid ... Also If i read it alone (without the help of a teacher) i might miss out the deeper meanings of the verses and commentaries. It speaks of things which i'm not familiar with. Things like pradhana etc. Do you think he introduces the beginner to such topics in this book?

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse if you find Swami Gambhirananda's book tough, please refer Swami Vireshwarananda's book. By the way pradhana simply means raw material used to manufacture something, like for the table, wood is pradhana.

Answer (score 1):

Nirguna Brahman according to Advaita has no mental state. So when I wrote 'Brahman was lonely' it was sloppy writing. I should have written 'Brahman as Viraj was lonely'. Who is Viraj?

> In the beginning, this [universe] was the self (**Viraj**) alone, in the
> shape of a person. He reflected and saw nothing else but His self. He
> first said: "I am He." Therefore He came to be known by the name I
> (*Aham*). Hence, even now, when a person is addressed, he first says:
> "It is I," and then says whatever other name he may have. And because
> He, before (purva) the whole group [of aspirants], burnt (aushat) all
> evils, therefore He is called Purusha. He who knows this verily burns
> up him who wishes to be [**Viraj**] in advance of him.

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad I.IV.1

> Viraj: The first embodied being, born of the Cosmic egg. He is endowed
> with a human form. It is important to remember that Sankaracharya uses
> the word Prajapati to denote both **Hiranyagarbha** and **Viraj**. **The former
> applies to Brahman when identified, through maya, with the totality of
> subtle bodies, and the latter, to Brahman when identified through
> maya, with the totality of gross bodies.**

Commentary of Brhadaranyaka Upanishad I.IV.1 by Swami Nikhilananda

I will add this explanatory material to that answer.

Comment: So both Hiranyagarbha and Viraj (according to Brihadaranyaka Up.) are saguna brahman?

Comment: Hiranyagarbha is Brahma and thus Isvara. So Hiranyagarbha is Saguna Brahman. Viraj may also probably be thought of as Saguna Brahman in the gross plane.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have been more clear in mg objection. This is now a very clear answer. 

Comment: Thank you Mr.Pradip. Is this viraj the same as what the dualists call virat purusha who's upper portion of the body contains the devas, the waist portion contains humans and lower portion contains the asuras?

Comment: Yes. Viraj is the same as Virat and is also known as Vaisvanar.